# Is there any program that can compare and synchronize location of file without delete and copy them all

Tags: synchronization, compare, backup

I have a little problem. I have a lot of image files stored on my PC at home.
I have copied them to an external hdd take to organize them into different folders(a lot of folder too) while holiday travel with laptop
Now I'm back home. Is there any program that can compare and synchronize location of files on PC with external hdd and move them exactly without needing to delete and copy them all?
Thanks.